# Getting "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver " while try to run selenium Grid code with Gecko driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, geckodriver

I am running basic *selenium* code with the help of *selenium Grid*.

Below are the steps:

**Step 1** :- Downloaded the latest version of *selenium Standalone server (3.4.0)*;

**Step 2** :- Created *HUB* by using command `java - jar <path of selenium standalone server>\\selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub` -> *run successfully*;

**Step 3** :- Created node using command `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -node http://localhost:4444/grid/register` -> *run successfully*;

**Step 4** :- Created a simple *selenium* program with below code:

```
public class ClassName {

  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
    DesiredCapabilities cap=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub");

    WebDriver wd1 = new RemoteWebDriver(url, cap);
    wd1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    wd1.manage().window().maximize();

    wd1.get("http://www.clickindia.com/");
    wd1.findElement(By.linkText("Post Free Ad")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    wd1.findElement(By.linkText("Select category manually")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    WebElement country = wd1.findElement(By.id("combo_0"));
    Select sel = new Select(country);
    sel.selectByVisibleText("Jobs");
  }
}
```

While running above code the following exception was thrown:

[image: Exception Image]

**Note** : If I run above code without *remoteDriver* and as a common *WebDriver* programm then it is working and running properly.

Location of selenium standalone server and Gecko file is same.

Gecko version is v0.16.0

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that Selenium cannot find GeckoDriver binary in:

1. Any of the locations that are part of  the `PATH` environment variable and
2. It could not find any valid value via the JVM argument (`System.getProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver")`) which represents geckodriver binary's location .

The line

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
```

ensures that only the current JVM (The JVM in which your `ClassName.main()` method is executing) knows of the location of the geckodriver binary. That is why your code runs fine when you work with `FirefoxDriver`.

But when you are working with `RemoteWebDriver` i.e., in the Grid mode, wherein you are trying to run against a Grid setup, setting the geckodriver location via the JVM argument `"webdriver.gecko.driver"` will not have any effect on the other JVMs (remember that the node which is responsible for supporting your browser interaction is spun off under a separate JVM using the command `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -node http://localhost:4444/grid/register` (Your **step 3**).

To fix this, you have two options.

1. You use the JVM argument `-Dwebdriver.gecko.driver` when you are spawning the node and specify the location of the geckodriver.
2. You download geckodriver binary into a folder and include its location as part of your [PATH](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) variable (i.e., add `C:\\geckodriver.exe` to your `PATH` variable)

Answer (score 1):

You have registered the node with default configuration as `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -node http://localhost:4444/grid/register`. So your node is unable to process the request.

You can consider registering the node with the following configuration as:

```
java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\\geckodriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Your code blocks works fine at my end.