# Selenium grid with node on same machine to run test on Chrome driver is hitting WebDriverException(chrome driver path is not set)

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I have linux box which starts hub and nodes on the same machine to run tests on chrome browser. On running test "WebDriverException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property" exception occurs.

if -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver.exe is added in command to start node, it works. But I have a complex system and this can not be added their is their any way to avoid adding -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=./chromedriver.exe in command while starting Grid Node? Is is possible to define in capabilites
? please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver " while try to run selenium Grid code with Gecko driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412384/getting-the-path-to-the-driver-executable-must-be-set-by-the-webdriver-gecko-dr)

Comment: Nope. its not a duplicate.. This is specific to chrome browser running on grid..